# How to upload .jar to AWS EC2 and restart JVM in which it's running?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, automation

I'm new to Amazon Web Services and I'd like to learn about best approaches to uploading .jar artifacts to EC2.

I have an EC2 Linux instance with Java server running on it. I'd like to have an easy and elegant way to update the server. As for now, I have to kill the server via SSH, upload new .jar via SFTP and then run the server again over SSH.

Is there a solution which would be better and more scalable than just scripting the above?

If it has any meaning, I work with IntelliJ IDEA, so a plugin for it would also suit.
Or may be there's a framework which takes over the updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how heavy-weight you need the solution to be, I would give CodeDeploy a look for this: http://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/details/

If you want something more lightweight:

- you could look at Ansible
- you could look at a cron-job that periodically pull the jar and it's new compared to what's running stops/copies/starts the service.
- there is nothing wrong with just SSH if we are talking about a few machines.

Comment: Thanks, AWS CodeDeploy looks perfect as it supports Git. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a cron running at every EC2 instance that checks for new JAR files (in S3 repo) and restarts your JVM each update. Kinda hacky but definitely more scalable than executing a script for each instance (especially if you want to use an auto-scaling group in the future)

Comment: Sounds quite good, but I'll have to set the task frequency too high (about a few minutes) or I won't be able to update the server in real time.

Comment: If you want a real time update it depends on what exactly you want to change in the JAR. If it's a code, it won't be real-time (restart downtime). If it's a configuration (assuming that it's a file on the classpath), consider an 'almost real-time' solution like monitoring an external file and replacing the config on change e.g.: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) combined with any service that downloads it from S3 (cron?, Java thread running AWS API calls, e.g.: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html))

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing relatively small app(s) and want to do it quick and dirty on your $400 windows lap top:

1. Get your keys from aws... do the conversion.
2. setup putty from step 1.
3. install winscp import the putty connections
4. run winscp ... click on aws ec2 instance in winscp.
5. drag and drop the springboot jar over to aws.
   --- the end ---